# Problems with my shell script... (grep)

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I'm sorry to be posting about another problem with the same script that I was working on yesterday.

Originally I had a problem with it `cd`ing to paths with spaces, though that is fixed now. The problem is that if a 3rd argument is given to the script, it is to search for it within the files it found earlier and then print the files location as well as the line number the term was found on.

For some reason `grep` isn't liking paths to files that contain spaces (again right? -.-) even though I have double quoted the variable I am `grep`ing.

Does anyone have any ideas about how to fix it?

```
#!/bin/bash

path = $1 #1st arg is the path to be searched
regex = $2 #2nd arg is a regular expression
searchTerm = $3 #3rd arg is an optional search term
startDir = `pwd` #Stores the starting path
getDirs()
{ #Function to get the directories
    for i in "$1"
    ; do
        if [ -d "$i" ]; then
            echo "$i" >> temp.txt
            getDirs "$i"
        fi
    done
}

getFiles() {        # Function to get files matching the regex

    while IFS= read -r path; do # While there is a line, read it, backslash is not a delimiter
        cd "$path"

        temp=`ls -1 | grep "$regex"`    #List the contents of the dir. Store only files that match the regex

        for j in $temp
        do
            echo "$path/$j" # For every file stored, print its location
        done
        cd $startDir
    done < temp.txt # Read from temp.txt
}

searchFiles() { # Function to search within files


    for a in $output1 # For every file found
    do
        out=`grep -n "$searchTerm" "$a" | cut -d: -f 1` # Find the line numbers in which it is present, stop showing after 1st :
        for i in $out   # For every line found
        do
            echo "$a: line $i"  # Print the file location, and the line numbers of the terms
        done
    done
}

numArgs=$#

echo "$path" >> temp.txt
getDirs $path   # Getting directories to search

output1=`getFiles`

cd $startDir

if [ $numArgs == 3 ] # If a search term is specified
then
    searchFiles # Then search the files for it
else
    echo "$output1" # Otherwise, just print the location of the files
fi

rm temp.txt # Removing temporary files
exit 0
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not via a link.  And if it seems too long, then it is!  You'd need to reduce it to a minimal test-case.

Comment: I've added the code now :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is with the searchFiles function, that's where my grep is

Comment: Are you sure the issue is with `grep`? Looking at the code, I'd consider `for a in $output1` as a possible issue, as that will likely break $output1 by spaces. What happens if you set an empty IFS before the `for` loop?

Comment: I tried putting double quotes around `$output1` and seemed to not work, if anything it made it worse

Comment: If the for loop will break by spaces, is there a possible alternative?

Comment: no space around "=" assignements. And put $1, $2; ... inside double quotes

Comment: I dont have spaces there, its a paste error, I'll add the quotes though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script has a LOT of problems including unquoted and incorrectly quoted variables. Here's how your getFiles function need to be written at a minimum (there are other issues like whether grep is really necessary and use of echo but I'm not touching those so this highlights the serious problems):

```
getFiles() {        # Function to get files matching the regex

    while IFS= read -r path; do # While there is a line, read it, backslash is not a delimiter

        if cd "$path"; then

            oIFS="$IFS" # save then reset and restore IFS to avoid work splitting on spaces, except newlines.
            IFS=$'\n' tempA=( $(ls -1 | grep "$regex") )    #List the contents of the dir. Store only files that match the regex
            IFS="$oIFS"

            for j in "${tempA[@]}"
            do
                echo "$path/$j" # For every file stored, print its location
            done
            cd "$startDir"

        fi

    done < temp.txt # Read from temp.txt
}
```

Note that "temp" is now an array, not a string, so you can access the file names it contains one at a time and still have each of them quoted. I just renamed it tempA to make it obvious that it's an Array.

So, update your script to use arrays instead of strings to hold your file names as demonstrated above, get rid of the spaces around the assignments, quote all of your variables, use $(...) instead of backticks, and change `grep -n "$searchTerm" "$a" | cut -d: -f 1` to `awk -v st="$searchTerm" '$0~st{print NR}' "$a"` then repost if you still have problems.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I'm relatively new to Bash having just been introduced to it at University and left to pretty much teach it to ourselves so I apologise for anything horribly bad :) I've managed to get my original script to work by manipulating spaces in the paths using `sed`. Though I will try to implement the improvements you've given me anyway, I need the practice! Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Do yourself a favor and do NOT do it the way you describe as that's like owning a bicycle and carrying it everywhere you walk - you can do it but people will look at you kinda funny! The resulting script also cannot help being riddled with bugs and difficult to enhance/maintain in future as it's using tools that are simply not designed for the job and guess what the response will be here if you post a question asking for help.

Comment: Note, your example code is still broken here for files containing whitespace.  The `tempA=( $(ls -1 | grep ...) )` expression will undergo word splitting.

Comment: @JoshCartwright yes, you're right. I'd set IFS=$'\n' before the operation - any better suggestion?

Comment: The solution is to avoid the use of the `$(ls -1 | grep ...)` construct altogether.  It is not possible to use properly with files with embedded whitespace.  If it is possible to assume GNU `find`, I would suggest making use of `find $dir -regex ...`.  If GNU `find` cannot be assumed, a bash loop over a glob expansion might work coupled with [[ a =~ b ]] (assuming a newer bash) or expr a : b.

Comment: @JoshCartwright - the ls will work with everything but embedded newlines just be setting IFS=$'\n' before the execution. I agree that piping the output of ls to grep is almost certainly the wrong approach but I'm trying to modify just the parts of his script that are clearly wrong and apply across his whole script.

Comment: I disagree with suggesting known-broken, non-robust solutions to problems.  Instead, we should be recommending as robust solutions as possible.  Here is an example of a robust GNU find solution: `find "${1-$PWD}" -type f ${2+-regextype posix-basic -regex "$2"} ${3+-exec grep -n "$3" /dev/null '{}' '+'}`

Comment: We should be recommending as concise solutions as possible. What problem does the extremely simple and portable `IFS=$'\n' ls | grep` have compared to that highly cryptic GNU-specific find command?

Comment: It does not properly handle files with embedded newlines (which you have admitted).  http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: IMHO it's not worth complicating your script and making it non-portable just to handle file names that contain newlines. It's just worth stating it as a caveat so the very few people in that situation and looking for a UNIX script to run on those files know to rename their files before running the tool (or request help writing a different tool).